# After the original user is deleted, the next user is assigned the same UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We noticed some strange behavior in our application, which resulted in the use of the same `uuid` twice.

User sign up and send request, first we create a `User` record, then we send some external requests that may fail. If those requests fail, we delete the `User` record.

In our case, the frontend app sends two identical requests at the same time, and because the first external requests fail for some reason, we delete the `User` record, but the `uuid` generated for that first `User` record is somehow passed to the second request and second `User` record. We know this because after creating each `User` record, we passed the `id` and `uuid` to an external service, and with such invalid data, we ran into some issues.

This is how `uuid` is generated:

```
t.uuid "uuid", default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
t.index ["uuid"], name: "index_users_on_uuid", unique: true
```

Simplified scenario:

1. User #1 created with `id` equal `100` and `uuid` equal `40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608`.
2. User #1 destroyed.
3. User #2 created with `id` equal `101` and `uuid` equal `40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608`.

Nearly all three actions take place at the same time.

Comment: Notice that first record was destroyed before second was created, so the constraint works fine. The same UUID was reused.

Comment: @dbugger, `gen_random_uuid()` is not time based it is a version 4 UUID that sets the clock and time components to constants per [Version 4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.4) and then generates random numbers for the rest of the bits.

Comment: I'm going to say something in the Ruby stack is caching values and that what you are seeing is that cached value reused. For someone to answer more definitively is going to require you adding(**to the question**) the Ruby code that is performing the actions.

Comment: The issue can be quickly resolved by simply moving the code that sends the user's id and uuid to another microservice after the user record is destroyed. That's when things began to go wrong. So, while the solution is straightforward, I wanted to comprehend the nature of the problem.

Comment: The nature of the problem is that your client code is caching values and reusing them and without seeing that code there is not more that can be said.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak The most straightforward solution for this scenario is to use the `after_create` hook to send the call to the external service. If it fails, the user record itself won't be created and you don't have to destroy the user record and run into this issue because of some caching.

Comment: @SachinSingh If at all possible, I prefer to avoid using callbacks.